# <li> tag not showing for guest in Joomla

Tags: html, joomla

I was modifying my client joomla website,

http://tours4women.net/component/bookpro/194-greece-athens-mykonos-and-santorini-2?Itemid=294

When we open the above mentioned webpage, which loads quickly. but problem is when we scroll down, after Calender and Available box, it should show 5-6 tabs which is not showing.

When i logged in the website, i mean registered user, i can see the tabs. Really confused where i messed. i have checked almost all files, not able to see where the actual error coming.

From inspect element, i can see ul tag but inside there is no li tag for guest. For Registered users i can li . Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: First you should look into the javascript that is throwing errors by the hundreds.  I shut the site down after ten seconds and the error count in the console was approaching 1,100.
VM400:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearData' of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have several javascript errors but this issue is a permission issue. For this particular module you need to check the permissions
[image]

Comment: Thanks. solved. i had one plugin called Anticopy. Once i disabled it started working again. Some settings i need to correct. Anyway happy now.